# Fill formula column wise when drag down by column in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, xlookup

I want to fill up a column of values using xlookup(). Please see the example below.
Typically the formula will automatically change parameters as I drag down the column but it only works if Var1-Var6 are populated by rows. But in the raw data Var1-Var6 are in columns (and cannot be easily transposed due to other constrains). I am wondering how I can make the formula automatically loop through column B to G when dragging down the column.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use INDEX:

```
=XLOOKUP($J$4,$A:$A,INDEX($B:$G,0,ROW($ZZ1)))
```

Now as it is dragged down it will change which column is returned.

[image]

with Office 365 we can also use filter and transpose:

```
=TRANSPOSE(FILTER(B:G,A:A=J4))
```

put that in the first cell and it will spill the results

[image]

Comment: Nice. I was going down the `Indirect(Char..` route, but yours is simpler.